# Are there any "canonical" sources of C. elegans connectome?

Tags: public-databases

I found that there are a couple of projects that allow the user to simulate the neural system of *C elegans*, for example OpenWorm one update being [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6158223/).

I don't know how to navigate sources in bioinformatics and thus struggle to evaluate their quality.

**Question** Are there any fundamental / most widely accepted data sources for raw data of C Elegans connectome or electron microscope scans of this organism, similar to Human Genome Project? If not, what are the ways to derive the data?

Answer (score 1):

*Answer from @terdon, converted from comment (please improve if possible):*

Have you checked on [WormBase](https://wormbase.org/)? That's the main repository for c. elegans data. I don't know that they have connectome data, but if they exist, that's where they will be stored.

*[see [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for more information on the purposes of comments in the StackExchange network]*